# ${a^3 + b^3\over a+b}$ for integer values $a$ and $b$.

Tags: polynomials, problem-solving, integers

I am new to this website so sorry in advance if my formatting is a bit off. I am trying to show that 
$${a^3 + b^3\over a+b}$$
is an integer when both $a$ and $b$ are integers. I have already looked at the numbers from $1$ to $10$ for values $a$ and $b$ and it has held up for some arbitrary numbers like $99$ and $-55$, however I am unsure how to approach showing that this is true (or untrue) for all integers.

Could anybody point me in the right direction or provide a solution?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division

Comment: Here is a good [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on formatting. In general, enclose your mathematical expressions in dollar signs: `$a^3$` gives $a^3$.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I will use this in future posts/comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the sum of two cubes can be factored as
$$a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT: use that $$a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the geometric sum is

$$\frac{1-q^n}{1-q}=1+q+\dots+q^{n-1}$$

Substitute: $q=\frac{a}{-b}$
$$\frac{1-\frac{a}{-b}^n}{1-\frac{a}{-b}}=\frac{1}{b^{n-1}}\frac{-b^n-a^n}{-b-a}=\frac{1}{b^{n-1}}\frac{a^n+b^n}{a+b}$$

Notice that
$$b^{n-1}(1+q+\dots+q^{n-1})$$
is an integer if a and b are integers